# No se puede iniciar sesión porque las cabeceras ya se han enviado

Tags: php, session, cabeceras-http

Me sale ese error al intentar loguearme como administrador:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Cabe agregar que en localhost me funciona de maravilla, pero es en el servidor donde falla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if (@!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}elseif ($_SESSION['rol']==2) {
    header("Location:index2.php");
}
?>
```

Posteriormente, puse el PHP primero que el HTML y tampoco me funcionó:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (@!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}elseif ($_SESSION['rol']==2) {
    header("Location:index2.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Administrador</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="SafeLife">
```

Comment: ¿Has confirmado que no haya ningún código antes de ese `<?php` al principio? Hasta un espacio en blanco, un carácter oculto o un salto de línea harán que te aparezca ese error.

Answer (score 0):

Agregar después de la primera línea

```
ob_start();
```

El motivo es limpiar el buffer para cualquier instrucción “echo” o html, de forma que no se envíe antes de las cabeceras y no suceda este error

Referencias

[enter link description here](https://phpfashion.com/everything-about-output-buffering-in-php)

Comment: Seria genial si en tu respuesta explicas el por qué de esa instrucción

Comment: Agregué un breve descripción, saludos

Answer (score 0):

> Una función útil que uso para el inicio de la sesión y nunca me ha dado problemas.

```
function checkSession() {
    if (checkStatedSession() === FALSE){
        @session_start();
    }
}

function checkStatedSession() {
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Simplemente la utilizas llamando a la función "checkSession" en lugar de llamar a session_start.

```
<?php
checkSession();
if (@!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}elseif ($_SESSION['rol']==2) {
    header("Location:index2.php");
}
?>
```